# Определить количество символов алфавита

Tags: c++

Всем привет. У меня есть задача. Нужно сделать программу с таким условием:
Определить количество символов алфавита, пароль состоит из k символов, время перебора которого было не меньше t лет.k=11,t=90,s=50. 
Предыдущие две задачи имели примеры решения вот их примеры:
Примеры.

> Пример 1.
>   Задание определить время перебора всех паролей, состоящих из 6 цифр.
>   Алфавит составляют цифры n=10.
>   Длина пароля 6 символов k=6.
>   Таким образом, получаем количество вариантов: С=nk=106
>   Примем скорость перебора s=10 паролей в секунду. Получаем время перебора всех паролей t= C/s=105секунд=1667минут=28часов=1,2 дня.
>   Примем, что после каждого из m=3 неправильно введенных паролей идет пауза в v=5 секунд. Получаем время перебора всех паролей T=t*5/3=16667секунд=2778минут=46часов=1,9 дня.
>   Итог = t+T = 1,2 + 1,9 = 3,1 дня
>
> Пример 2.
>   Определить минимальную длину пароля, алфавит которого состоит из 10 символов, время перебора которого было не меньше 10 лет.
>   Алфавит составляют символы n=10.
>   Длина пароля рассчитывается: k=logn C= lg C.
>   Определим количество вариантов C= t * s=10лет*10 паролей в сек. = 10*10*365*24*60*60=3,15* 109 вариантов
>   Таким образом, получаем длину пароля: k=lg (3,15*109) = 9,5
>   Очевидно, что длина пароля должна быть не менее 10 символов.

Их я переделал под себя налегке. Но тут возник вопрос: Как определить количество символов алфавита. Я прикинул что в первой задаче n-количество символов алфавита, значит например мне нужно n найти. Но в задаче оно фигурирует в формуле нахождения количества вариантов. Но с формулы C=n^k никак n не вынесешь. Над второй задачей думал тоже, там еще интересней ситуация: Там у нас фигурирует количество алфавита в качестве основания под логарифм. И опять такие основания я не могу вычислить. Может вы мне сможете пролить свет на решение этой задачи. Буквально пинка не хватает чтобы сообразить. Если надо коды двух предыдущих задач я скину.

Comment: Что мешает записать формулу расчета времени и выполнять ее в цикле увеличивая n до тех пор пока расчетное время не станет больше t ?

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, у вас нет ограничения на то, что все символы пароля не должны повторяться. Тогда всего вариантов паролей n<sup>k</sup>, при подборе со скоростью s общее время n<sup>k</sup>/s >= t, откуда, логарифмируя, получим

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для ваших значений s=50, k=11, t= 90*3.155e<sup>7</sup>

n >= 10.3 - итого, n = 11.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: и по моему тоже